# How can I check if the user can see and click on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It is simply possible to find all truly visible and clickable elements in the page using the `document.elementFromPoint` function. However, it returns `null` for elements outside of the viewport.

So, how to find all clickable and visible elements in the full page? The visible elements are not just limited to the styles. Just consider a container `<div>` which is now hidden behind all children elements. So, the parent `<div>` is not longer visible.

[image]

So, do you have any idea how it is possible to find all *really* visible elements in the page? In the example above, obviously “Parent `<div>`” is not visible practically. There are some other unpredictable situations where those elements may not be visible and the styles (`display`,`visibility`, etc.) may not indicate it.

My final intention: I want to check if an element is *really* visible and clickable for the end-user or not. As an example use case I want to find all possible zones a user may click on.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Tushar does not answer the question. The parent div is not visible for the end-user in my example, but it returns true in view-port measurements.

Comment: @Xufox "How to find visible elements for the end-user?". I am hope the question be clear.

Comment: XY problem is not about whether the question is clear or not. I’m just trying to figure out, why you would ever want to find visible elements for the end-user and whether there’s a broader problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: @Xufox I want to check if an element is `really` visible for the end-user or not. Use case? for example I want to find all possible zones a user may click on.

Comment: I'm confused... technically the parent DIV _is_ visible in this example, so your definition of "visible" is completely circumstantial. In many cases, the child DIVs will have transparent backgrounds, so the parent's background may be visible!

Comment: @ArthurKay You are right. However, it can be also hidden. I am going to update the question. In fact, I should explain it based on available click zones.

Comment: Then my next question would be, why do you want to get all possible click zones like that? One way of dealing with arbitrary click zones is to attach a `click` listener to the `window` (`window.addEventListener("click", function(e){`…`});`) and inside the function, check with `e.target`, which element has been clicked and then you can even decide with an `if` statement and `e.preventDefault();` what to do with that click and whether to ignore it or not.

Comment: Maybe you should reword this question along the lines of: "How can I check if the user can see an element or not?"

Comment: @Xufox I need to find all possible zones in advance. My use case is too complicated as I am going to use this result for a machine learning algorithm for analysis purposes for comparing thousands of pages. Above Chuck Le Butt comment is so accurate.

Comment: @Kousha Okay, _that_ was a satisfying response. _And_ that’s a tough problem…

Comment: You might not be able to gather all the data at once. Technically if it's not in the view port it's not visible, so why not attach a scroll event that gathers the new clickable/viewable elements at the end of the scroll event?

Comment: @scrappedcola Unfortunately, I can not control the end user experience and scroll the page. I understand if an element is not in the viewport, it is not logically visible, but technically it is. Just I am busy thinking of a proper and a professional way of something like jQuery implementation of `:visible`, which is not working in this case.

Comment: Even if elements outside the viewport could be retrieved, you can’t assume that a website is completely static and has no movement whatsoever. An element could still appear when hovering something else or some other thing. Knowing one static state beforehand might not be the best approach.

Comment: I wasn't saying you should control the experience and scroll for them. You can attach a listener that waits for the scroll event and then you could 'refresh' your knowledge of the page.

Comment: @scrappedcola This limits the usage and it can be considered just as a hack. In the first line of the question I just started with this idea. However, in my use-case it is not possible.

Comment: Find a very large monitor to borrow / rent.

Comment: @CarolMcKay I like your solution lol

Comment: @Xufox Logically, your statement is true. The UI may change based on the scroll position. However, at the current state of the scroll, all DOM elements are available and accessible for any function. So, it is possible define the current state regardless of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstand the basics behind events in domApi.
there will be bubbles and captures in any event happened at the client.
you must have seen code like this `document.addEventListener('click',function(){},false)`,

that means to use bubble instead of capture to handle event.
so actually clickable dom element is related with whether or not DOMJs uses bubble or capture

Comment: I am not sure if you have reviewed the question.